# The Professor's Shopping List

Tags: knowledge, word-property

My school had recently hired a new professor, and I volunteered to assist while he moved into his new classroom. He happily accepted my help. I walked into the classroom, and saw him unpacking some boxes.

*"So what class are you going to be teaching?"* I asked.

*"You don't need to worry about that,"* was his reply. *"Oh, and by the way. Could you run to the store and grab those items for me. I forgot to get them earlier."*

*"Sure..."* I said, still confused.

As I headed out the door, I wondered why he hadn't told me which subject he taught. I looked at the list he had given me.

> - Squash
> - Quiche
> - Raw Broccoli
> - Yellow Bathrobe
> - LED Lightbulb
> - White Turmeric
> - Microwave Popcorn
> - Sweet Potato
> - Stuffed Wolf
> - Disposable Phone
> - Can of Tuna

As I read it again, I suddenly understood.

*"That man is a genius!"* I yelled as I headed off to the store.

**What did I learn from the professor's shopping list? Why?**

Comment: WTF is a "Heartburn Antibiotic"? And do you seriously send a colleague to a store to purchase you a luxury car like a Porsche???  If I saw the shopping list, I'd think anything but 'that man is a genius'...

Comment: To make a slightly more palatable (and affordable) shopping list, you could have One Pound Tuna / Can of Tuna, yellow (or white) turmeric, brioche / quiche

Comment: Fair point. The things one doesn't notice until after it's done. : )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You learned that the professor teaches:

> **Chemistry**

Since:

> his 'shopping list' is not actually a shopping list; instead it's his way of communicating to you the subject he teaches. You can tell he is a chemist because the lines of the list end in the sequential symbols of the first 11 elements in the [Periodic Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_table):
>
>  Squas**H**
>  Quic**He**
>  Raw brocco**Li**
>  Yellow bathro**Be**
>  LED lightbul**B**
>  White Turmeri**C**
>  Microwave Popcor**N**
>  Sweet Potat**O**
>  Stuffed Wol**F**
>  Disposable Pho**Ne**
>  Can of Tu**Na**

Comment: I wonder how a music professor's list look like.

Comment: Challenge Accepted. (maybe) : )

Comment: It might begin with "The Picture of Dorian Gray" and an Aeolian harp, but continuing that list seems like it would be troublesome.

Comment: What about "Xyrtec, 10 mg"